# What does these ES6 syntaxes really change?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to learn some functional javascript and es6 concepts.

I have an array

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var raw =[
  {
    key :"name",value:"henry"
  },
  {
    key :"age",value:"old"
  },
  {
    key :"food",value:"matooke"
  },
  {
    key :"kids",value:"Acacia"
  },
  {
    key :"garbageA",value:"kasailoA"
  },
  {
    key :"garbageB",value:"kasasiroB"
  },

]
```

I am trying to filter out data with garbage keys . I have two codes that return different results and I wonder why they do not return the same results.
When i write

```
const endShape = _(raw)
.filter(key =>!/garbage/.test(key));
console.log(endShape);
```

in my console it prints.

```
[ { key: 'name', value: 'henry' },
  { key: 'age', value: 'old' },
  { key: 'food', value: 'matooke' },
  { key: 'kids', value: 'Acacia' },
  { key: 'garbageA', value: 'kasailoA' },
  { key: 'garbageB', value: 'kasasiroB' } ]
```

showing that my filter dint work.

When i write

```
const endShape = _(raw)
.filter({key} =>!/garbage/.test(key));
console.log(endShape);
```

It brings a syntax error.

But when i write

```
const endShape = _(raw)
.filter(({key}) =>!/garbage/.test(key));
console.log(endShape);
```

my filter works well and it prints

```
    [ { key: 'name', value: 'henry' },
  { key: 'age', value: 'old' },
  { key: 'food', value: 'matooke' },
  { key: 'kids', value: 'Acacia' } ]
```

Why is it this way ? yet i know from phat arrow syntax that its okay to write

```
var x = y=>y+1;
```

and also

```
var x =(y)=>y+1
```

Comment: in the first example ... key would be an object such as `{
    key :"name",value:"henry"
  }` etc, however,  `({key})` syntax is [Destructuring Assignment: Unpacking fields from objects passed as function parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) - your first code would work if you did `.filter(item =>!/garbage/.test(item.key));`

Comment: note: in modern javascript (since you mention es6 concepts, this holds true), you don't need `underscore` to perform these functions - replace `_(raw)` with `raw` - it all still works the same

Comment: Underscore is not my problem. I can change that.

Comment: `.filter()` passes the array element to the callback.  Your array element is an object.  It's not the `key` property.  You need to compare to the `key` property of that object in order to filter on it.

Comment: I know it's not your problem, I never said it was your problem

Comment: I just need clear explanations of thise syntaxes I  the function. Thank you

Comment: Indeed, sorry I mentioned it

Comment: If you want to use destructuring (`{key}`), parenthesis for the parameters are mandatory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the first and the second key for your filter is quite different.

On the first run when you do:

```
const endShape = _(raw)
.filter(key =>!/garbage/.test(key));
```

You are passing an object from your `raw` array, and your check is being evaluated like:
`!/garbage/.test({ key: 'name', value: 'henry' })`
Which will always be evaluated to false, and then you negate it so every condition will be true, thus your filter let every entry pass.

On the second run you do:

```
const endShape = _(raw)
.filter(({key}) =>!/garbage/.test(key));
```

Where you're [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) `key` from your object, and thus the test makes sense, and your filter works fine!

Hope it helps!